# Prove comparison test for improper integrals

Tags: calculus

Trying to prove the convergence theorem for integrals.
Suppose $0\leq g(x) \leq f(x) \,\forall x \ge a$ and ($f,g$ both integrable).  Prove that $\int_{a}^{\infty}g$ converges provided that $\int_{a}^{\infty}f$ converges.

my attempt:
I know $0 \le \int_{a}^{t}g \le \int_{a}^{t}f \, \forall t\ge a$ and so $0 \le \int_{a}^{\infty}g \le l$, where $l=\int_{a}^{\infty}f$.  But how does this show that $\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{a}^{t}g$ converges?  My assumption is that I have to prove this limit exists, but how are we assured that the limit does not oscillate like crazy for values between $0$ and $l$?  Any idea how to finish the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $0 \le g(x) \; \forall \; x \ge a$. This means

$$h(t) = \int_{a}^{t}g(x)dx \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

is an increasing function in $t$. In particular, the value will not oscillate at all, as you are concerned about. Also, since it's bounded above by

$$l = \int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

as stated in the question, then

$$\lim_{t \to \infty}\left(\int_{a}^{t}g(x)dx\right) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

must converge to a limit point itself, call it $L$, with $L$ being such that

$$0 \le L \le l \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

One way to see this to consider a sequence $y_n = h(n)$ for integers $n \ge a$. This is a monotone, bounded (below by $0$ & above by $l$ in \eqref{eq2A}) sequence. Regarding proving, and other details, about these sequences always converging, there are proofs in books such as [Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus](https://www.amazon.ca/Elementary-Analysis-Calculus-Kenneth-Ross/dp/1461462703) by Kenneth A. Ross. Also, there are also various posts here, such as at [Bounded monotone sequences and convergence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3553105/602049), [Clarification on the proof that all bounded monotone sequences converge](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1953666/602049), [Every bounded monotone sequence converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/609030/602049), and [Question on proof concerning : A bounded, monotone sequence converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2055531/602049).

Comment: Hmm, how do I show the "it must converge to a limit point itself" rigourously? ie. how do I show such an $L$ indeed exists?  Intuitively it makes sense, I just want to see how it is done.

Comment: For instance, $\lim_{x \to 0}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is bounded between $0$ and $1$ but the limit does not exist.

Comment: It is because the function $h$ is increasing: an *increasing* function that is bounded above has a limit at $+\infty$ (or more generally left- and right-limits at any point).

Comment: @SaranWrap The key issue here is the sequence is monotonic, non-decreasing, with an upper bound. I added some details about using the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, which I hope helps to explain why.

Comment: @SaranWrap You're welcome. Note I just did a site search of "bounded monotone sequence converge" (but without the double quotes) to find quite a few other posts here asking about this issue, with my providing links in my answer to $3$ of these. If you like, you may wish to read those, or other related posts, for more details about this issue.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I do not uderstand your argument with BW. Also, the result "increasing + bounded above => convergent" is often used to prove BW.

Comment: @Raoul Thanks for your feedback. Re: using the argument with BW, if you have an infinite monotone subsequence converging, note any points not included, after the first included one, must have included points both before & after it, so it's bounded by those converging points, so these other points must also be converging. I only added this to help give a conceptual idea. Although, as I recall, the BW theorem can be proven in other ways, since it's not directly related to the answer, plus there's so much printed & online info., I removed that paragraph & added to my last one with more details.